# Concerns about using a 3D tileset grid

Tags: 3d, graphics, graphics-programming, grid

I'm thinking of implementing a 3D tile system for my engine, and tie it to it's world streaming system as well. As in, using it for it's terrain for an open world in an engine that theoretically can support up to about 80 kilometers squared even if it won't be fully used.

The game will be making use of both free form movement, and tiled movement when it comes to combat. With cover systems involved.

I was wandering about a few questions.

How viable is it to use a bunch of smaller tiles for terrain? Think Dota 2 Reborn. Where the increased levels are guaranteed to be flat and at exact heights. And there will be hills and the like connecting them.

If I was to use tiles, do I need to weld the vertexes and recompute the normals for the affected vertices?

If I do not need to connect them, will it cause any visible artifacts? Or any sort of performance hits? I know I can batch all the standard tiles. But I don't think the same can be said if I treat the terrain tiles like normal terrain when it comes to texturing.